# Кнопка на пересечении границ, как лучше реализовать

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, css-selectors

Имеется input,  как на картинке справа снизу[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как его лучше реализовать, желательно что бы при адаптации эта кнопка не улетала  никуда, если это возможно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

через [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp) адаптивите как вам угодно (хоть тут пример без `input`'a, но смысл один)

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

.container__button {
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: pink;
  border-radius: 15px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px;
  right: -75px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container__button">Some text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
.wrp {
  position: relative;
  height: 90vh;
  max-height: 500px;
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: chocolate;
}

.button {
  position: absolute;
  right: -100px;
  bottom: -25px;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: gray;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrp">
  <div class="button"></div>
</div>
```